# UI stuck while trying to show progress of each file upload in listview

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask, box-api

I am trying to show the progress of multiple files while I upload them to Box.com in a ListView. I am using a Donut Progress bar I found from this link https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress to show the progress for each item in the list.

However, I can't seem to update the UI while I am uploading. The UI is stuck and does not even respond to clicks by the user. The progress bars for each item starts with 0% and only changes to 100% once every upload has finished. All percentage in between are not shown since the UI is stuck.

I am currently using a custom view for each item in the listview. I did that because I wanted each view to implement a progress listener. Then I added each view to their respective async tasks and update the progress from there.

The following is my code:

Adapter I am using for the ListView

```
public class SurveyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private LinkedList<File> files;
private static LinkedList<String> savedIDs;
private ViewHolder holder;
private BoxApiFile mFileApi;
private HomeActivity homeActivity;
private int [] progress;
private int mScrollState = AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
private ListView listView;
private File file;

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView fileIDTextView;
    TextView dateModifiedTextView;
    DonutProgress fileUploadProgress;
    CustomSurveyView customSurveyView;
    UploadToBoxTask uploadTask;
}

public SurveyListAdapter(HomeActivity homeActivity, LinkedList<File> files, ListView listView) {
    this.homeActivity = homeActivity;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(homeActivity);
    this.files = files;
    savedIDs = new LinkedList<>();
    progress = new int [files.size()];
    this.listView = listView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return files.size();
}

public File getItem(int position) {
    return files.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    file = files.get(position);
    holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.survey_list_view, null);
        holder.customSurveyView = (CustomSurveyView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customSurveyView);
        holder.fileUploadProgress = holder.customSurveyView.getDonutProgress();
        holder.fileIDTextView = holder.customSurveyView.getFileIDTextView();
        holder.dateModifiedTextView = holder.customSurveyView.getDateModifiedTextView();
        holder.uploadTask = new UploadToBoxTask(this, holder.customSurveyView, file);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String fileShouldStartWith = HomeActivity.FILE_SHOULD_START_WITH;
    String fileShouldEndWith = HomeActivity.FILE_SHOULD_END_WITH;

    String ID = fileName.substring(fileShouldStartWith.length(), fileName.length() - fileShouldEndWith.length()).trim();
    savedIDs.add(ID);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy   hh:mm a");
    String lastDateModified = sdf.format(file.lastModified());

    holder.fileIDTextView.setText("Subject ID " + ID);
    holder.dateModifiedTextView.setText(lastDateModified);

    return convertView;
}

public View getViewByPosition(int pos) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}

public static LinkedList<String> getSavedIDs() {
    return savedIDs;
}

public void syncWithBox(BoxApiFile mFileApi){
    this.mFileApi = mFileApi;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) getViewByPosition(i).getTag();
        holder.fileUploadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.uploadTask.executeOnExecutor(executor);}

    executor.shutdown();

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }

    System.out.println("Finished uploading");
}

private class UploadToBoxTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    SurveyListAdapter surveyListAdapter;
    BoxUploadProgressListener progressListener;
    File uploadFile;

    public UploadToBoxTask(SurveyListAdapter surveyListAdapter, BoxUploadProgressListener progressListener, File uploadFile){
        this.surveyListAdapter = surveyListAdapter;
        this.progressListener = progressListener;
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final BoxRequestsFile.UploadFile request = mFileApi.getUploadRequest(uploadFile, BoxConstants.ROOT_FOLDER_ID);
            request.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(long numBytes, long totalBytes) {
                    publishProgress((int) (100 * (numBytes/totalBytes)));
                }
            });
            final BoxFile uploadFileInfo = request.send();
            showToast("Uploaded " + uploadFileInfo.getName());
            //loadRootFolder();
        } catch (BoxException e) {
            BoxError error = e.getAsBoxError();
            if (error != null && error.getStatus() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CONFLICT) {
                ArrayList<BoxEntity> conflicts = error.getContextInfo().getConflicts();
                if (conflicts != null && conflicts.size() == 1 && conflicts.get(0) instanceof BoxFile) {
                    //uploadNewVersion((BoxFile) conflicts.get(0), position, adapter);
                    publishProgress(100);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            showToast("Upload failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers){
        progressListener.onProgressUpdate(integers[0]);
        showToast(String.valueOf(integers[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param){

    }
}
}
```

The custom view I created:

```
public class CustomSurveyView extends RelativeLayout  implements BoxUploadProgressListener{
View rootView;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
TextView fileIDTextView;
TextView dateModifiedTextView;
DonutProgress donutProgress;

public CustomSurveyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustomSurveyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_survey_view, this);
    linearLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileInfoLayout);
    fileIDTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileIDTextView);
    dateModifiedTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.dateModifiedTextView);
    donutProgress = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileUploadProgressBar);
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(donutProgress, "progress", donutProgress.getProgress(), progress);
    donutProgress.setProgress(progress);
    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
    invalidate();
}

public LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
    return linearLayout;
}

public TextView getFileIDTextView() {
    return fileIDTextView;
}

public TextView getDateModifiedTextView() {
    return dateModifiedTextView;
}

public DonutProgress getDonutProgress() {
    return donutProgress;
}
}
```

Progress listener interface I created

```
public interface BoxUploadProgressListener {
    void onProgressUpdate(int progress);
}
```

This is what my layout looks like

[image: app layout]

Please help correctly update the UI with the progress of each upload. I've been at this for two days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Its the while loop I put after the executor. It kept on running till all tasks were finished.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause :

1. Avoid changing Ui from Async task
2. Avoid adding new Thread along with every holder instance, it increases RAM consumption due to which app is not responsive.

Create Interface and update the UI in Main thread.

Comment: Thats not the problem. Thanks for the help though.